# Can I pull an image without Internet when the image exists in docker registry-mirror?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I create a registry mirror. Can I pull an image without Internet? I have created a mirror using this command:

```
docker run -d -p 5555:5000 -e STORAGE_PATH=/mirror -e STANDALONE=false -e MIRROR_SOURCE=https://registry-1.docker.io -e MIRROR_SOURCE_INDEX=https://index.docker.io -v /Users/v11/Documents/docker-mirror:/mirror  --restart=always --name mirror registry
```

When I pull an image like hello-world:

```
docker pull image
```

I can find the image in local path what I set "/Users/v11/Documents/docker-mirror". Does it mean I succeed in creating mirror? But, I closed the Internet, and delete the hello-world:

```
docker rmi hello-world
```

and pull again, but it failed. I want to know whether I must use mirror with Internet? if not, what is wrong with me?

By the way, I have started docker daemon with this ENV:

```
docker --insecure-registry 192.168.59.103:5555 --registry-mirror=http://192.168.59.103:5555 -d &
```

and 192.168.59.103 is my boot2docker ip.

Answer (score 1):

In your configuration you specified a *non-standalone* setup using a `MIRROR_SOURCE_INDEX`. So whenever you want to search for an image that index is queried. The other `MIRROR_SOURCE` gets queried for the image itself.

You might be able to retrieve an image offline with a `pull` request (that has already been pulled before while you were online). But you are not able to issue `docker search` commands when the index is not available.

If you want to be completely independent from the public docker registry then you would need to setup your own private registry.

Comment: By the way: if you want to play around a little bit you can try this [simple private registry](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/h3nrik/simple-registry/) and this simple [registry mirror](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/h3nrik/simple-registry-mirror/) containers.